# Android SplitScreen orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation, split-screen

I have an issue.

I have a method which checks if screen is in landscape mode:

```
private boolean isLandscape() {
    final Resources resources = getResources();

    return resources != null && resources.getConfiguration() != null
            && resources.getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
}
```

It works perfectly when screen is not split.
The problem is the next:

It returns `false` when screen is split.
In this case `resources.getConfiguration().orientation` returns `ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT`. I have read android reference([#1](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html), [#2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)), but I did not found any information.

- Device: Nexus 5x
- OS: Android 7.0

Any suggestions?

Comment: Gone through this link ?  https://medium.com/google-developers/5-tips-for-preparing-for-multi-window-in-android-n-7bed803dda64#.tiw9in4e6

Comment: @Stallion no. There is important phrase: 
>Multi-window takes advantage of the resource system by adjusting the configuration based on the size of your window — screen size is the obvious one, but the smallest width (i.e., the minimum of the width or height) and the orientation are also updated when resizing.

Comment: @Stallion it helped me.  I understood the source of problem.

Comment: Cheers, happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully to the link provided by [Stallion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/991094/stallion), I found the reason:

> Turns out: “portrait” really just means the height is greater than the width and “landscape” means the width is greater than the height. So it certainly makes sense, with that definition in mind, that your app could transition from one to the other while being resized.

See [this link](https://medium.com/google-developers/5-tips-for-preparing-for-multi-window-in-android-n-7bed803dda64#.fs79jhpjm) for more information.